# rsync doesn't run when from a bash script

Tags: command-line, bash, rsync

I have wakeup script that runs when the system wakes up (Arch linux)

```
$ cat /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/example

#!/bin/bash
 case "$1" in
 resume)
 echo "hey I just got resumed!"
/usr/bin/bash /home/user/bin/wakeup_script
 esac
```

my wakeup_script

```
$ cat bin/wakeup_script

#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/touch /home/user/testwake.txt
/usr/bin/rsync -vaz user@xx.xx.xx.xx:/home/user/downloads/test.txt /mnt/data/
/home/user/bin/mnt d
```

you can see that the script "wakeup_script" contains three bash script. When the system wakes up, the first and third script runs very well but rsync never worked, I tried scp, it doesn't work again! what's wrong here?

when I execute the same "wakeup_script" in a shell, the rsync does work but it doesn't get executed when the system wakes up!!

```
$ /usr/bin/bash /home/user/bin/wakeup_script
```

Comment: Does the `rsync` command rely on an SSH identity from your user's `~/.ssh`? when run by root (from pm-utils) it will be looking in `/root/.ssh` instead

Comment: Maybe network is not available yet? Try to redirect the output of your script to a file to investigate what goes wrong. `/usr/bin/bash /home/user/bin/wakeup_script &> /tmp/wakeup.log`

Comment: yes, it requires SSH key. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

In `/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/example`:

after the line:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

add the line:

```
sleep 15
```

This will give 15 seconds for network interfaces to become available after resuming.